# Issues with connecting Google Analytics to Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have been using Power BI to connect to Google Analytics now for several months,however in the last month all of my reports are failing with the following error:

"GoogleAnalytics: Request failed (403): Quota exceeded for quota group 'default' and limit 'Queries per 100 seconds' of service 'analytics.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:664933364861'. Table: xxxxxxxxxxxx"

This has never been an issue before, and no new reports have been created, so I'm puzzled as to why it is happening.

I went onto the Google Developer Console, and under the Analytics Reporting API, I can't see any data at all so I can't actually see how far over the quota I am going (if that is indeed the issue)

I have amended the quotas to the highest values allowed, and still get the same error when refreshing.

Does anyone have any advice that may be able to point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

This has been happening to me for a while. Goes away for a bit and then comes back. It's happening to quite a few people.

See https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/Google-Analytics-API-Error/idi-p/893610

Answer (score 0):

Power bi's connector for google analytics has its issues, such as sampling and API Calls limit.

You might be better off, connecting Google Analytics with Google BigQuery and then to Power bi.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).